# Add custom property to mvc selectlist

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, selectlist

I need to create a selectlist with a list of items. I need to check a property on the selected item in jquery when the ddl is changed. How and where can i put this property? It would be perfect if it was in some sort of data attribute on each option, is this possible?

Comment: Do you need it to be reusable, or is this a one-time feature?

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#selecID").change(function(){
// check the selected option attribut here
// change the attribute value like $("option:selected",this).attr("id","changed");
alert($(this).val());

});
```

[`jquery change`](http://api.jquery.com/change/)

here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/DBXGe/1/

select the option then select another option and then select the previously selected option you will see the id changed...

Comment: is selecID the drop down list? I need to set the property somehow, not just retrieve it...

Comment: yes you will have to specify the the `ID` of you dropdown here, can you post some html

Comment: Thanks, but that's not what i want, i need to create a property MyProperty on the drop down list (instead of id) and then i need to add a value for each item for that property when i set up my ddl on the server side, then when the ddl selec option is changed i need to retrieve MyProperty on the client side and hide/show some fields. So retrieving isn't the problem, setting is :/